# multidimensional linear regression for y = A *x + B

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, regression

Is there any standard method / function which exists for solving this problem given a set of values for y and x?

For 1D variables y and x there seems to be but for N-D variables y and x we would have A an NxN matrix and B an Nx1 vector.

The only solutions I have seen assume that y is 1 dimensional which isn't obviously helpful.

Currently my only solution has been to do N^2 linear polynominal fits to get sets of coefficients of the form

y(j) = a_jk x(k) + b_jk

and then get a vector B by taking the average of b_jk.  I am not convinced this is the optimal solution to the problem.

Comment: You mean multivariable linear regression

Comment: I'm not sure I do, that seems to be only for scalar y.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model seems to be what I am asking about.

Comment: a ND variable is a multidimensional system. In coordinates, `[x y z]` is N-D variables, in 3-Dimensional world. They are 3 1D variables that are independent of each other, so a dimension each.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you looking for this? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html

Comment: From your question, multivariate regression is what you're looking for (as Ander mentioned). The 1D case you describe is just regular regression, but your outcome Y can also take a matrix form, and hence be multidimensional. There are many ways to solve this. Although it would help if you provided a concrete example as its not entirely clear what you mean by multidimensional in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use least squares to find A and B to minimise

```
Q = Sum{ (A*x[i]+B - y[i])'*(A*x[i] + B - y[i])}
```

(Here ' denotes transpose, and I'm assuming you have the vectors x[0]..x[N-1] and y[0]..y[N-1])

While you could do that with a standard linear least squares solver, here's another way:

Compute the mean xbar of the x's and the mean ybar of the y's, ie

```
xbar = Sum{ x[i]}/N
ybar = Sum{ y[i]}/N
```

Compute the following matrices

```
C = Sum{ (x[i]-xbar)*(x[i]-xbar)'}
D = Sum{ (y[i]-ybar)*(x[i]-xbar)'}
```

Compute A and B

```
A = D*inv(C)
B = A*xbar-ybar
```

Note that we can only compute A if C is invertible. What this amounts to is that the x[] vectors must span the space they lie in. If they don't then A isn't determined uniquely.

The proof that the above recipe solves the problem isn't that illuminating; let me know if you want to see it.

Comment: This is the correct answer, sorry I took so long to respond.

Answer (score 1):

Cris Luengo, is indeed correct in the comments. The function `mldivide` doubles as a least square solver

> If A is a rectangular m-by-n matrix with m ~= n, and B is a matrix with m rows, then A\B returns a least-squares solution to the system of equations A*x= B

So if you have the equation

```
y == A * x + B
```

Then you will first have to subtract `B` from both sides and then apply `mldivide`, so something like

```
xhat = A\(y-B);
```

Comment: I don't think you have understood the question, x and y are the things I have, I want to fit A and B to the equation.